# PHP — How to determine number of parents of a child array?

Tags: php, arrays, parent

I'm not so strong with arrays but I need to determine how to count the number of parents a child array has in order to determine the indenting to display it as an option in a SELECT.

So, if I have this array:

```
array(
      'World'=>array(
            'North America'=>array(
                  'Canada'=>array(
                       'City'=>'Toronto'
                   )
            )
      )
);
```

How would I go about determining how many parents 'City' has in order to translate that into the number of spaces I want to use as an indent?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT: Let's see if I can explain myself better:**

I have this code I'm using to build the OPTIONS list for a SELECT:

```
function toOptions($array) {

    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
        $html .= "<option value=\"" . $key . "\" >";

        $html .=  $value['title'];

        $html .= "</option>";

        if (array_key_exists('children', $value)) {
            $html .= toOptions($value['children']);
        }

    }

    return $html;

}

print toOptions($list);
```

So, I'm trying to determine how to get the number of parents in order to add spaces before the title in this line:

```
$html .=  $value['title'];
```

Like:

```
$html .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $value['title'];
```

But, I'm not sure how to figure out how many spaces to add.

Hopefully this is more clear.

Thanks for any help so far.

Comment: You want to know that number only for `City` or for all keys in the array?

Comment: It depends on the scope.. if the current scope is that you just have the array('city' => 'Toronto') within some function, you have no way of finding out, unless you know something else about the array, like certain keys etc..

Comment: How did you come to access 'City' without knowing how you got there?

Comment: Are you building a menu? Because if you are, you should be asking what's the best way of building a recursive menu structure in PHP. But that has already been answered

Comment: What is the code you use to create the select? I'm sure you can easily add white space handling there (at least this would not require another loop over the nested arrays).

Comment: I guess for any of the keys. I'm essentially wondering if there's anything like array_num_parents().

Comment: @Dolph: It's just an example.

@amoths: "in order to determine the indenting to display it as an option in a SELECT"

@Felix: Yes, but I need to know HOW MUCH whitespace.

Comment: @AJB: Just modify the `visit()` function that I described below for doing the html concatenation. You have the depth so you know how much spaces you have to put in.

Comment: @Murilo: Thank you, I'm sure this does work. I'm just trying to figure out how to wire it up and make it work.

Comment: @Murilo: I'm not sure how I already have the depth. As I mentioned, I'm lame when it comes to arrays.

Comment: @AJB: See your `toOptions()` like my `find_recursive()` and the part where you build the $html my `visit()` function. You only have to make a few adjustments :)

Comment: @Murilo Vasconcelos: Ha. Yes, I got so far as to see how my 'toOptions()' function was the same as your 'find_recursive()', still working out the other part. If you want to just, you know, post the answer then I promise I won't look at it until I figure it out;)

Comment: Got it. Thanks a tonne for your help Murilo. I understand this much better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$x = array(
      'World'=>array(
            'North America'=>array(
                  'Canada'=>array(
                       'City'=>'Toronto'
                   )
            )
      )
);

// This function do something with the key you've found in the array
function visit($name, $depth)
{
    echo $name . ' has ' . $depth . ' parents.'; 
}

// This function visits all the contents aff $array
function find_recursive($array, $depth = 0)
{
    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $value) {
            visit($k, $depth + 1);
            find_recursive($array, $depth + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

For visiting:

```
find_recursive($x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well. Off the top what you are dealing with is a multi dimensional array.

You could run a count w/ foreach on each level of the array, and use the count number returned +1 for each level the foreach loops through.

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but I am trying to see exactly what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for helping me narrow down what I was having a problem with OldWest.

Answer (score 1):

As you are already using a recursive function to display that data, you can just extend your function. There is no need to traverse the array more often than one time:

```
function getWhitespaces($count) {
    $result = '';
    while($count--) {
        $result .= '$nbsp;';
    }
    return $result;
}


function toOptions($array, $level=0) {

    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
        $html .= "<option value=\"" . $key . "\" >";

        $html .=  getWhitespaces($level) + $value['title'];

        $html .= "</option>";

        if (array_key_exists('children', $value)) {
            $html .= toOptions($value['children'], $level + 1);
        }

    }

    return $html;

}

print toOptions($list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.. Your solution screams for recursion in my mind. Its a bit ugly but it seems to work

```
$totraverse = array(
    'Moon' => array(
        'Dark Side' => "Death Valley"
    ),
    'Halley Commet' => "Solar System",
    'World' => array(
        'North America' => array(
            'Canada' => array(
                'City' => 'Toronto'
            )
        ), 'South America' => array(
            'Argentina' => array(
                'City' => 'Toronto'
            )
        )
    )
);


function traverse($totraverse_, $path="", $count=0) {
    global $array;
    // echo count($totraverse_) . " count\n";
    if (!is_array($totraverse_)) {
        echo "returning $path and  $key\n";
        return array($path, $count);
    } else {
        foreach ($totraverse_ as $key => $val) {

            echo "assting $path and  $key\n";
            $result = traverse($val, $path . "/" . $key, $count + 1);
            if($result){
                $array[]=$result;
            }
        }
    }
    echo false;
}

$array = array();
traverse($totraverse);

foreach($array as $item){
    echo "{$item[0]}--->{$item[1]}\n";
}
```

Comment: You could avoid the `global $array` in your function buy adding `&$array` as fourth parameter.